# Pygame won't let me make boundaries on a screen with the event module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm just making a simple game that allows a red rectangle to move around the screen, but the boundaries that should make the red rectangle stop before it gets off the screen won't work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
while Game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5
                if x > display_width - 100 or x < 0 and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x_change = -5
                    else:
                        x_change = 0   #I did this for all directions
x += x_change
y += y_change
```

Just so you know, clock.tick is 80 and I have imported pygame and did the pygame.init() thing. Also, movement and every thing else works, just not this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def clamp(value, minimum=0, maximum=1): return max(minimum, min(value, maximum))


maxX = display_width-rectangle_width
maxY = display_height-rectangle_height

if x not in range(maxX): x_change = 0
if y not in range(maxY): y_change = 0
x = clamp(x, maximum=maxX)
y = clamp(y, maximum=maxY)
```

However, you are changing the velocity and not the position, when it is out of the screen, the velocity is not moving it back, it keeps there or the speed from the pressed key in the next frame moves it again.